# Change push notification alert message

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

How do I change push notification's alert message. I need to process the Unicode string as shown in the screenshot. [image: screenshot]

I tried checking my notification service extension but I couldn't find any way to process the userInfo["alert"] property.

Comment: Good question, I never faced such issue...(y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change you notification service extension code:

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

    if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
        // Modify the notification content here
        // Convert received string
        let data = bestAttemptContent.body.data(using: .utf8)!
        // Apply encoded string
        bestAttemptContent.body = String(data: data, encoding: .utf16)

        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing bestAttemptContent.title = "I am awesome" but the title apparently is still my "alert" though @.@

Comment: I did some digging and testing and apparently the property to be changed is body instead of title? Just want to clarify with you.

Comment: @Happiehappie Sure, if `body` works then use that. I just brought `title` as an example because it depends on your PN implementation.

Comment: For now, since I started this thread, you mind changing your snippet to body? I would like to accept your answer.

Comment: I've changed the snippet to use `body`, if it helped you could upvote the answer too :)